# Problem with function on the Angular component

Tags: angular

I am trying to get a way to call a function inside my component only after loading, as long as the component is loaded, several times my function is called and I do not want this, here is my code:

```
<div class="form-group" [ngClass]="aplicaCssErro('name')">
    <label>
        NAME
    </label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" formControlName="name" autocomplete="off">
</div>
```

My function:

```
verificaValidTouched(campo){
   return !this.formulario_cadastro.get(campo).valid  && this.formulario_cadastro.get(campo).touched;
}

aplicaCssErro(campo){
    console.log(this.verificaValidTouched(campo));

   return{
     'has-error': this.verificaValidTouched(campo),
     'has-feedback': this.verificaValidTouched(campo)
   }
}
```

The functions only serve to add a validation class in my data-driven form. What I want, is to just call those functions that are in my HTML after I've loaded the page or something better than this, because when loading the page the functions are called several times. Can anyone tell me a solution?

Comment: then you have to call function ones and store class in a variable.angular change detection cycle call these function over and over

Comment: this can be done using `Subjects` take a look at subjects and observables

Comment: it happens since this is how angular check bindings. Best practice is seting a variable upon your change and bind that variable.

Answer (score 1):

You should utilize an Angular lifecycle hook, probably ngAfterViewInit to call function after the page has finished initializing.

https://angular.io/api/core/AfterViewInit

Lifecycle hooks are a good way of utilizing Angular's API:

https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks